# Why am I getting "PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context" error?

Tags: sql, plsql, subquery

I am a newbie when it comes to PL/SQL. I have the following block of PL/SQL code:

```
FUNCTION  evaluate(p_sid IN NUMBER, p_min_len IN NUMBER, p_max_len IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_res VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    v_res := evaluate_batch(CURSOR(SELECT sid, stext FROM maintable WHERE sid = p_sid), p_min_len, p_max_len);

    RETURN v_res;

END eval_ocr_quality;
```

where

```
TYPE text_rec_t IS RECORD (
        rec_id NUMBER,
        text CLOB);
TYPE text_rec_cur_t IS REF CURSOR RETURN text_rec_t;

FUNCTION  evaluate(p_sid IN NUMBER, p_min_len IN NUMBER := 3, p_max_len IN NUMBER := 3) RETURN VARCHAR2;

FUNCTION  evaluate_batch(p_cur IN text_rec_cur_t, p_min_len IN NUMBER := 3, p_max_len IN NUMBER := 3) RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

I get `PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context` error at the `v_res := evaluate_batch` line

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `t_rec_cur_t` is defined as a cursor returning a TYPE, but the `SELECT` in your function returns two columns - SID and STEXT. Did you perhaps want to cast those two columns as a `text_rec_t` instance? Try `SELECT CAST(SID, STEXT) AS TEXT_REC_T FROM MAINTABLE...` etc. Best of luck.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis Thanks, tried it but got the same error

Answer (score 1):

Open the cursor separately and pass it in:

```
FUNCTION  evaluate(p_sid IN NUMBER, p_min_len IN NUMBER, p_max_len IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_res VARCHAR2(255);
    c     TEXT_REC_CUR_T;
BEGIN
    OPEN c FOR SELECT TEXT_REC_T(sid, stext) FROM maintable WHERE sid = p_sid;

    v_res := evaluate_batch(c, p_min_len, p_max_len);

    -- May need to close cursor c here if not closed in evaluate_batch

    RETURN v_res;
END eval_ocr_quality;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: For some reason I am getting `PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword` for the `OPEN` line

Comment: I had the type constructor syntax wrong. Give it another go.

Comment: Now a different error: `ORA-00904: "TEXT_REC_T": invalid identifier`

Comment: The declarations for `TEXT_REC_T` and `TEXT_REC_CUR_T` are show in the question. Where are these declarations? Are they in a package?

Comment: The declarations are in a file `foo.pks` that gets loaded with `@foo.pks;`. The other code is in the corresponding `foo.pkb` that gets loaded with `@foo.pkb;` and that's when I get the error

Comment: TYPEs declared in a package can't be use in an SQL statement, as the Oracle SQL engine doesn't know about TYPEs declared as part of a package. (PL/SQL and SQL are logically separate in Oracle). If you want to use this TYPE in an SQL statement you'll have to declare the TYPE as an independent type using the `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE` statement. Best of luck.